# How can I use Makefile to autobuild Windows Mobile applications without MS

Tags: windows-mobile, build, makefile

In my project, I want to build Windows mobile application into installation files automatically without human click on MS.

How can I achieve it?  Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using devenv to do something similar:

```
TARGET      :=  MyProject
VSDIR       :=  C:/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\ 9.0/Common7/IDE
DEVENV      :=  $(VSDIR)/devenv

all:
    $(DEVENV) ./$(TARGET).sln /Rebuild
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an msbuild file or call devenv.exe with a command line parameter.